# insert special characters in local database for titanium

Tags: javascript, android, sql, titanium

I want to insert special characters like '@', ''', '"','&' etc in titanium local database.
can any body tell me that what's the exact way of doing that. I've searched but couldn't find.
currently i'm using this query to insert data

```
var passaction='string plus any special character//& ';
var db = Titanium.Database.open('dogs');


db.execute('INSERT INTO myinfodb (id, company) VALUES(?,?)', 1, passaction);
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your database file is in UTF-8 this shouldn't be a problem, just include the special characters inside a single-quote:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO myinfodb (id, company) VALUES('®™ other characters')", 1, passaction);
```

Comment: Wierd, you could base64encode them and put them in there? Or some type of intermediate parsing?

Comment: should i put special characters in values like this VALUES('@','&','"')   ?

Comment: That will just put them in different columns. Are you sure your DB is UTF-8? You may have to set a PRAGMA command as well